# Insert data from XML/JS function to table using MySQL/PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, xml

I am writing a web application that displays car information in a table, and the vehicle information comes from an XML file.  When the user clicks on a row in the table, more information is displayed about the car.

I want to have a button saying "Add to Collection" where if clicked, the vehicle's information will be inserted into a MySQL table.  However, I am confused on how to access this information with PHP, since my program is using JavaScript to pull and display the information.

Here is the JavaScript script that pulls the information from the XML file, creates the HTML table with one car/row, and displays more information about the vehicle when the user clicks on the table entry:

```
<p id='showCar'></p>
<table id="demo"></table>

<script>
  var i;
  var x,xmlhttp,xmlDoc
  xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.open("GET", "cars.xml", false);
  xmlhttp.send();
  var xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;
  var table="<tr><th>Year</th><th>Make</th><th>Model</th></tr>";
  var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("CAR");

  for (i = 0; i <x.length; i++) {
    table += "<tr onclick = 'displayCar(" + i + ")'><td>";
    table += x[i].getElementsByTagName("YEAR")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    table += "</td><td>";
    table += x[i].getElementsByTagName("MAKE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    table += "</td><td>";
    table += x[i].getElementsByTagName("MODEL")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    table += "</td></tr>";
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = table;

  function displayCar(i) {
    document.getElementById("showCar").innerHTML =
    "<strong>Make:    </strong>" +
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("MAKE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "<br><strong>Model:    </strong>" +
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("MODEL")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "<br><strong>Year:    </strong>" +
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("YEAR")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "<br><strong>Safety Rating:    </strong>" +
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("RATING")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "<br><strong>Compaints:    </strong>" +
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("COMPLAINTS")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "<br><strong>Common Problems:    </strong>" +
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("COMMONPROBLEM")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "<br><strong>Recalls:    </strong>" +
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("RECALLS")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "<br><strong>Image:</strong><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <img src='" +
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("IMAGE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +"' width = '320' height = '240'>";  //button to add car to collection will be around here
    }

</script>
```

Here is a sample entry from the XML file:

```
<CAR>
  <MAKE>Audi</MAKE>
  <MODEL>A4</MODEL>
  <YEAR>2013</YEAR>
  <RATING>5.0</RATING>
  <COMPLAINTS>95</COMPLAINTS>
  <COMMONPROBLEM>Steering, Engine, Electrical System</COMMONPROBLEM>
  <RECALLS>4</RECALLS>
  <IMAGE>https://static.nhtsa.gov/images/vehicles/8169_st0640_046.png</IMAGE>
</CAR>
```

I want to use PHP to insert all the different attributes into a Car table with MySQL (table attributes match XML attributes name for name), but I was unsure how to initiate this process and ensure that when the user presses the button, only the data for the car being displayed is inserted into the table.

Comment: You'll need to use another Ajax request to send the data to the server so PHP can process it.

Comment: @ADyson thank you!  Feeling a little silly for having this slip my mind, but in my defense I’m still learning.  Got it to work perfectly with your suggestion!  Thanks again.